# FCM push notification via topic triggering twice

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm building an animal adoption app with a student of mine, and we are getting the following bug, that seems to have appeared by itself as we didn't even touch the FCM part again:

**Step 1**

When we add a new Animal to the Firestore db, we also send a push notification via POST (We don't have a custom backend and this is for school so we do it like this)

```
    private fun sendNotificationToServer(animal: Animal, animalId: String) {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://fcm.googleapis.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val service = retrofit.create(FCMService::class.java)

        val notification = FCMNotification(
            to = "/topics/animales",
            notification = null,
            data = FCMAnimalData(
                idAnimal = animalId,
                tipoAnimal = animal.tipoAnimal.animalString,
                base64Image = "",
                title = "Nuevo animal",
                body = "Se ha añadido un nuevo animal a la lista. Haz clic para conocerlo!",
                timestamp = Timestamp.now().seconds
            )

        )

        val call = service.sendNotification(notification)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<ResponseBody> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ResponseBody>, response: Response<ResponseBody>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    Log.d("NOTIFICATION POST SUCCESS", response.message())
                } else {
                    Log.d("NOTIFICATION POST FAILURE1", response.message())
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ResponseBody>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.d("NOTIFICATION POST FAILURE2", t.message.toString())
            }
        })

    }
```

This works as intended and we get the notification inside `MyFirebaseMessagingService`

**Step 2**

Of course, we override `onMessageReceived` to handle the notification.

Here we get the notification's data and insert it into a Firestore collection (limit of 5) so we can show a "notifications history" view in the app:

```
        val fcmData = remoteMessage.data
        sendNotification(fcmData["title"] as String, fcmData["body"] as String)
        firestore.collection(ALERTS_TABLE_NAME)
            .add(FCMAnimalData(
                base64Image = fcmData["base64Image"] as String,
                idAnimal = fcmData["idAnimal"] as String,
                tipoAnimal = fcmData["tipoAnimal"] as String,
                title = fcmData["title"] as String,
                body = fcmData["body"] as String,
                timestamp = fcmData["timestamp"]?.toLong() as Long
            )).addOnSuccessListener {
                Log.d("NOTIFICATION", "ADDED")
                firestore.collection(ALERTS_TABLE_NAME).get().addOnSuccessListener { notificationList ->
                    if (notificationList.size() > 5) {
                        firestore.collection(ALERTS_TABLE_NAME).document(notificationList.first().id).delete()
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Error description**

Expected: When we go to the app's "notification history" view, the last notification appears once

Actual: The notification appears duplicated in the list

We have already checked that token handling is working fine, actually, when debugging we see that we are only entering `onMessageReceived` once and we only get one push notification.

When looking at the Firestore collection we can see the following:

- Two identical documents were created, one with tipoAnimal = "Perro/Gato" and the other with tipoAnimal = ""
- The documents have exactly the same timestamp.

It may be possible that we are getting this error since we started sending the animal's type into the server, but it shouldn't be a problem since we are sending just a string (the animalString value):

```
@Parcelize
data class Animal(
    @DocumentId var id: String = "",
    val nombre: String = "",
    val edad: Int = 0,
    val imagenBase64: String = "",
    val raza: String = "",
    val descripcion: String = "",
    var favorito: Boolean = false,
    val tipoAnimal: TipoAnimal = TipoAnimal.PERRO,
    val procedencia: TipoUsuario = TipoUsuario.PARTICULAR,
    val idUsuario: String = "",
    val timestamp: Long = 0
): Parcelable

enum class TipoAnimal(val animalString: String) {
    PERRO("Perro"),
    GATO("Gato")
}
```

Thanks in advance to anyone that can help me understand why the notification gets duplicated.

Comment: Maybe this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-use-firebase-cloud-messaging-on-android-d92cb4b53cfe) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseCloudMessaging).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some days, I figured out what was happening, it was pretty obvious but I didn't see it until now.

Quoting my question:

> We have already checked that token handling is working fine, actually, when debugging we see that we are only entering onMessageReceived once and we only get one push notification.

Here is the problem, we add the notification into the database inside `onMessageReceived`, that means that each active phone that receive a FCM push notification will insert the notification into the database. In our case we had two phones so the notifications got shown twice in the "notifications history" fragment.

I will be also quoting this:

> Two identical documents were created, one with tipoAnimal = "Perro/Gato" and the other with tipoAnimal = ""

This was caused because my student was working with an old version of the app that didn't have that parameter, but Firestore was managing it by setting a default value of ""